# How to turn off carousel when resized?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the `<div id=Slider class="carousel slide" data-ride=carousel>` displaying some images and text.

How can I disable the carousel when a mobile device is at the site? I want to improve the google score for mobile device.

If screen width <= 767 then remove carousel

Anyone can help with a js hack / css setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you simply need `.hidden-xs` class to disable that carousel.

```
.hidden-xs -->  Extra small (less than 768px) hidden
```

Learn more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_responsive_utilities.htm).

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap you can simply add a class to hide elements based on size.

<768px

```
<div id=Slider class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride=carousel>
```

> =768px

```
 <div id=Slider class="carousel slide hidden-sm" data-ride=carousel>
```

> =992px

```
<div id=Slider class="carousel slide hidden-md" data-ride=carousel>
```

> =1200px

```
<div id=Slider class="carousel slide hidden-lg" data-ride=carousel>
```

Comment: ^^ way better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you simply need to use a media query on the screen with CSS3.

Here is a list of media queries for all the different screen sizes:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

So, yours would look something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px){
    #Slider{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This is saying: if the max width display is 768pixels, do not display the container with the id of (whatever the ID is).

Comment: In which css file belongs this? Do i have to overwrite something from the original css bootstrap ?

Comment: In whatever you use for your general site styles.  As long as you include that after your bootstrap css file, you should be fine.  Your CSS styles are applied in the order they are read - which is why they are "cascading".

Comment: Oh, you may need to make that min-device-width: 768px.  I'm mobile so I can't test it quickly.  Let me know so I can update my answer, please.